# Is it necessary to re-evaluate a variable that refers to another variable if that variable changes?

Tags: variables, language-agnostic

If I have this program:

```
BEGIN
string = "Big Blue Hats."
count = 1
char = string[count]
WHILE char NOT '.'
    count = count + 1
    #do I need to evaluate 'char = string[count]' again in order to update 'char'?
ENDWHILE
END
```

Do I need to include in the loop `char = string[count]` in order for the value of `char` to be updated to refer to `char[2]`?

I suppose it depends on whether variables store the data values they are directed to (such as `'B'`) or the directions to get to that value (`string[count]`)? What exactly is stored in a variable? Does this vary with language?

Comment: That depends on language whether default behavior is _call by reference_ or _call by value_.

Comment: @SohaibFarooqi you mention 'default behaviour', so does that mean that this can be changed or set by the programmer?

Comment: Call by reference or value refers to calling functions, not to evaluating statements. This can never be changed or set by the programmer, it's a property of the language. (But of course you can pass references by value...)

Comment: Okay, I understand, thanks @alain

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it varies with language.
In almost all languages, `char = string[count]` would have to be reevaluated.

The languages which will automatically update `char` are called [Reactive Programming Languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactive_programming).

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You have to reevaluate it all the time because this variables have static values. It doesn't change unless you change it.